# How to regain lost access to encrypted data, known lock pattern

Tags: samsung, data-recovery, encryption, lineageos, android-12

My S10e is running LineageOS 19.1, rooted with Lygisk.
After one specific reboot after changing the SIM card, it entered a boot loop where it showed the Lineage boot animation for a few minutes, then reboots.
I never got to the unlock screen anymore.

After reinstalling bootloader etc. as well as dirty flashing LineageOS, the phone boots up again but I don't get access to data on the interal /sdcard.
The partition is accessible but all files/folders are encrypted.
Trying to access them in TWRP terminal (or trying anything else like Nandroid backup) I always get the error "*Required key not available*".

So, my questions are:

- can I in some way bring the phone's software to exactly the same state as before and making it recognise data, so that I can decrypt it?
- will enabling phone encryption again and using the same lock/encryption pattern be sufficient? (I fear not)
- Or is my assumption that it should be possible to reconstruct the key when using the same lock pattern on the same hardware & software flawed in general?
- EDIT:
- Is there any kind of redundancy of storing keys in LineageOS, which would allow to restore the original one?
- I do have a SeedVault backup - does it include the original encryption keys?

Comment: Only in some old Android versions the cryptographic key (for the user data partition) was directly derived from the lock pattern/pin/password. On recent versions this is not the case instead random generated keys are used, protected e.g. using GateKeeper, so I doubt that you will be able to "reconstruct" the key. Not sure how exactly the keys management works on LineageOS.

Comment: /sdcard actually is /data/media so it's very unlikely you have decrypted /data

Comment: @alecxs I didn't mention /data but "data" on /sdcard, more specifically user data mounted from /dev/block/platform/13d60000.ufs/by-name/userdata

Comment: */dev/block/platform/13d60000.ufs/by-name/userdata* is the only *rw* partition, all other partitions are mounted *ro*. **all** data is saved in */data*. My best guess is the encrypted files in */data/media/<user>* belong to another profile and therefore cannot decrypted with same credentials like the rest of files?

Comment: Ok, maybe I mixed things up, seeing different paths at different stages via adb shell vs TWRP terminal. Current situation is I see all those encrypted folders in */data/media/0* which belongs to my original profile (there never was any other profile on the phone).
Shouldn't I see a *fileencryption=* parameter in fstab somewhere (there is none)?

Comment: if the flag is gone in /vendor/etc/fstab* it must happened by magisk or any zip. this [TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-exynos-twrp-3-5-2_9-for-s10e-s10-s10-update-2021-06-07.4067765) can handle LOS encryption

Comment: @alecxs Thanks for the TWRP link, never found that one while searching for a TWRP with encryption support for Samsung devices. However, what do you mean by "*can handle LOS encryption*"? *twrp decrypt* says "no crypto support was compiled into this build" just the same as the latest TWRP official one.
Access to /data/media/0 fails with "permission denied" instead of seeing encryted files, though.
And I don't have */vendor/etc/fstab*, just /etc/fstab. Does it make any sense to add *fileencryption=* parameter there? If so, what syntax exactly, any non-default values with it?

Comment: (LOS) LineageOS FBEv1 encryption is supported, but Samsung encryption is not. maybe yours is FBEv2. /etc/fstab is from TWRP, you need to mount /vendor

Comment: @alecxs Did mount /vendor and found */vendor/etc/fstab.exynos9820*, it contains the expected *fileencryption=* param.
How would I make TWRP use it, too? Tried using the same line in */etc/fstab* and /etc/recovery.fstab* to no avail.

Comment: @alecxs Which fstab file does TWRP use?
Is there any way to tell if LOS FBEv1 or v2 is used (I'm on LOS 19.1)? 
twrp decrypt says "*Attempting to decrypt...*" but then still "*Not crypto support was compiled into this build*"
And finally: should I rather move this conversation to XDA?
I'll only be able to look into this again coming monday, though...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.